# How to substract two strings

Tags: java, string

I have started learning Java and have some across some difficulties. I'm trying to subtract two strings.

for example, with these strings;"032"&&"100". I want to be able to subtract each number individually so that the answer would be "032".

I have tried using substring, and parsing the two values to ints, but don't know what to do next. I have also tries using a for loop, to go through each arrays of the strings.

I do not expect for anyone to do this for me, but I would love to get some insight,or to tell me that i'm headed in the right direction

thanks

```
public static String appliquerCoup( String combinaison, String coup ) {

String nouveauCoup="";

  if(combinaison!=null&&coup!=null){
         for(int i=0;i>combinaison.length();i++){
            int a = Integer.parseInt(combinaison.substring(i, i + 1));
            int b = Integer.parseInt(coup.substring(i, i + 1));
            nouveauCoup=String.valueOf(a-b);
                if(a-b<0){
                  nouveauCoup=0;

                  }   
               }      

      } // main
     return nouveauCoup;
```

}

Comment: If you substract the String digit -wise, wouldn't you get -132 as output?

Comment: What's the logic by which subtracting "100" from "032" yields "032"? Or is that a typo? Do you need to handle only 3-digit numbers?

Comment: How subtracting 032 and 100 result in 032? Shouldn't be 068 or something?

Comment: I'm confused at what you want - `32 - 100` does not equal `32`.  But if you wanted `"-68"` as a result, you could do this: `String s = "" + (Integer.parseInt("32") - Integer.parseInt(100));`.

Comment: @Turing85 is right. At least this should be the result given Jusras explanations.

Comment: actually, my assignment is to subtract each number individually; 0-1;3-0;2-0. if, for one of the subtractions, i get a negative number it would stay as a "0".that's how you get"032". Thank you for helping though and sorry if my explanations weren't clear.

Comment: You should write these detail into the post. Also, show us, what you have tried so far so we get an idea where you are stuck

Comment: @Jusra,that's your real problem.I have the solution and would have posted an answer,but unfortunately,the question is put on hold as unclear. :-(

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correctly. you want to subtract each digit individually.
So (0-1), (3-0), (2-0).  The following program does this (yields -132):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String A = "032";
    String B = "100";
    String str = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length(); i++)
    {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(A.substring(i, i + 1));
        int b = Integer.parseInt(B.substring(i, i + 1));
        int c = a - b;
        str += String.valueOf(c < 0 ? 0 : c);
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Essentially, extract the i-th character of each string, convert them to integers, then do the subtraction.  Convert the result back to a string and append it to the result string.

Comment: You need to add the negative test.

Comment: I am going to throw a wrench at this.  What happens if you have these two values "032" and "190"?

Comment: Thank you for the help, I posted some of my code. I did use a for loop, the problem is that i'm not allowed to use StringBuilder.hehe.

Comment: for "032" and "190", the answer would be "002"

Comment: I just edited this solution to include the negative test it needed.  Now, if you add "032" and "190" it yields "002" as Jusra expected.

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to return "002",without StringBuilder? That's where I'm struggling, lol/

Comment: Change StringBuilder for String and replace the 'append' line with: 
`str += String.valueOf(c < 0 ? 0 : c);`. Then, remove the `toString()` from the `System.out`